# Did MS remove Windows+X keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10

This was one of my favourite shortcuts on W7/8 whichever it was added, but it doesn't seem to work on my W10 PC now. Has it been removed/changed/replaced?

Comment: Win+X should work in Win 10. Might be your keyboard. Try to use other shortcuts as Win+D for desktop to see if it is your Win key. Try to restart and see if it changes.

Comment: See here below. Windows Key + X is used for shutdown options.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026425/windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @John oh. It used to bring up control panel didn't it? For some reason R & D & Lwork but not X. Perhaps some override. These comments would be fine as an answer, they clarify it's my issue not Widnows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Logo Key + X is still there. See this Microsoft Support Article that shows it is used for Shutdown Options.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026425/windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: It does [a lot more](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-winx-menu-how-access-it) than just the Shutdown Options.